# Prove that the area of the triangle formed by the centers of the circumferences ex-inscribed is $\frac{abc}{2r}$

Tags: proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

> Prove that the area of the triangle formed by the centers of the circumferences ex-inscribed is $\frac{abc}{2r}$, where $a,b,c,$ are the sides of the triangle and $r$ is the inradius.

I know that
$S=s(r_a-a)\\
S=s(r_b-b)\\
S=s(r_c-c)\\
S=sr$

But I think this won't be useful...
How can I prove this?
Thanks for attention.

Comment: By "ex-inscribed" do you mean these orange circumferences? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Incircle_and_Excircles.svg

Comment: Yes, @CalvinLin !

Comment: $S=s(r_a-a)$ is wrong, it should be $S=(s-a)r_a$, same change for $r_b,r_c$.

Answer (score 1):

Before proving this, you need to prove few things (that I'm not proving) which will be helpful to prove the ultimate statement.

1. $\triangle ABC$ is the pedal triangle of $\triangle I_1I_2I_3$ with $I$ as it's orthocentre.
2. If $I_1, I_2$ and $I_3$ be the centres of the escribed circles which are opposite to the vertices $A, B$ and $C$ respectively of $\triangle ABC$. Then, $$I_1I_2=c\,\text{cosec}\frac{C}{2}$$
3. If $I$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$, then $$IA=\frac{r}{\sin\frac{A}{2}}$$

[image]

The area of $\triangle I_1I_2I_3$ is given as $A$

$\begin{align}
&=\frac{1}{2}(IA) (I_2I_3)+\frac{1}{2}(IB) (I_3I_1)\frac{1}{2}(IC) (I_1I_2) \\
&=\frac{r}{2}\left(\frac{a}{\sin^2\frac{A}{2}}+\frac{b}{\sin^2\frac{B}{2}}+\frac{c}{\sin^2\frac{C}{2}}\right) \\
&=\frac{r}{2}\left(\frac{abc}{(s-b)(s-c)}+\frac{abc}{(s-a)(s-c)}+\frac{abc}{(s-a)(s-b)}\right) \\
&=\frac{abcr}{2}\left(\frac{s}{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\right) \\
&=\frac{abcr}{2}\left(\frac{s^2}{\Delta^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{abc}{2r}
\end{align}$

Here, $s=\displaystyle\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ and $\Delta=$ Area of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: Would you like to accept the answer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $\rho=\tfrac12(a+b+c)$,
$a=|BC|$, $b=|AC|$, $c=|AB|$,
$r$ and $r_a,r_b,r_c$ denote the inradius 
and the corresponding exradii of $\triangle ABC$,

\begin{align} 
r_a&=\frac{\rho r}{\rho-a}
,\quad
r_b=\frac{\rho r}{\rho-b}
,\quad
r_c=\frac{\rho r}{\rho-c}
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
[O_aO_bO_c]&=[O_aCB]+[O_bAC]+[O_cBA]+[ABC]
,\\
&=\tfrac12(ar_a+br_b+cr_c)+\rho r
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Substitution of \eqref{1} into \eqref{2}
gives

\begin{align}
[O_aO_bO_c]&= 
\frac{\rho r\,(2\rho^3-(a+b+c)\rho^2+abc)}{2(\rho-a)(\rho-b)(\rho-c)}
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
&=
\frac{\rho^2 r\,(2\rho^3-2\rho\rho^2+abc)}{2\rho(\rho-a)(\rho-b)(\rho-c)}
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
&=
\frac{\rho^2 r\,abc}{2\rho^2r^2}
=
\frac{abc}{2r}
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

The same area in terms of exradii is

\begin{align}
[O_aO_bO_c]&=
\frac{(r_a+r_b)(r_b+r_c)(r_c+r_a)}{2\sqrt{r_a r_b+r_b r_c+r_c r_a}}
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}